# Karabiner not working (Mac OS Sierra)

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, blender

I found out that after I upgraded to Mac OS Sierra a few days after it was released, Karabiner didn't work any more.

I am using a MacBook Air, so it doesn't have a numpad but I need it to work more conveniently in the 3D software Blender to change views. Karabiner already came with an option that does <kbd>Fn</kbd> + any number = keypad of that number, including dots, slashes, commas, etc. However this didn't work any more after I updated, so I tried it in the XML file as shown below but that didn't work either.

Does anyone know how I would be able to get this feature working again?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Change numeric keys to keypad</name>
    <identifier>private.change_numeric_keys_to_keypad</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_0, ModifierFlag::FN | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_0</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_1, ModifierFlag::FN | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_1</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_2, ModifierFlag::FN | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_2</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_3, ModifierFlag::FN | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_3</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_4, ModifierFlag::FN | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_4</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_5, ModifierFlag::FN | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_5</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_6, ModifierFlag::FN | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_6</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_7, ModifierFlag::FN | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_7</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_8, ModifierFlag::FN | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_8</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::KEY_9, ModifierFlag::FN | ModifierFlag::NONE, KeyCode::KEYPAD_9</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the pqrs.org website:

> Karabiner does not work on macOS Sierra at the moment.
>
> We are developing Karabiner-Elements which provides simple key
>   modification for macOS Sierra at first. (Karabiner-Elements works well
>   on macOS Sierra. We are working on fixing several remaining issues.)
>
> We'll start updating for the full featured Karabiner for Sierra after
>   Karabiner-Elements is completed.
>
> https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements